# How can I apply a regex (l3regex) on items in a sequence? [LaTeX3]?

Tags: latex3, l3regex

I am trying to apply a regular expression to a string item from a sequence in LaTeX3.

## Example

Compiles with error, but only by pressing return many times.

```
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text>
                \inaccessible
l.64 \listprint[separator={ \par }]
```

### Documents.txt

Input file Documents.txt in same folder as source tex file:

```
test1_de.tex
test1_en.tex
test2_de.tex
test2_en.tex
```

### Source TeX File

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\listset}{O{default}m}
 {
  \macmadness_listset:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\listprint}{+O{}}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { macmadness/lists } { #1 }
  \macmadness_print_list:V \l__macmadness_list_name_tl
  \group_end:
 }

\seq_new:N \l__macmadness_list_separator_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \macmadness_listset:nn % Command called by \listset (see above)
 {
  \seq_clear_new:c { l_macmadness_list_#1_seq }
  \tl_set_from_file:Nnn \l_macmadness_file_contents_tl {} {#2}
  \seq_set_split:cnV { l_macmadness_list_#1_seq } { ~ } \l_macmadness_file_contents_tl
  \seq_pop_right:cN { l_macmadness_list_#1_seq } \l_tmpa_tl
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn {cnV}

\keys_define:nn { macmadness/lists }
 {
  name .tl_set:N       = \l__macmadness_list_name_tl,
  name .initial:n      = default,
  action .code:n       = \cs_set_eq:NN \__macmadness_action:n #1,
  action .initial:n    = \use:n,
  separator .tl_set:N  = \l__macmadness_list_separator_tl, % output delimiter
  separator .initial:n = { ,~ }, % output delimiter
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \macmadness_print_list:n #1
 {
  \seq_if_empty:cTF { l_macmadness_list_#1_seq }
   {
    $\langle$ \textit{empty~list} $\rangle$
   }
   {
    \seq_clear:N \l_macmadness_output_seq
    \seq_map_inline:cn { l_macmadness_list_#1_seq }
     {
     \tl_set:Nn \l_filename_tl { ##1 }
     \regex_replace_all:nnN {(.*)[\c{_}|.] } { \1 } \l_filename_tl
     \seq_put_right:Nn \l_macmadness_output_seq { \__macmadness_action:n { ../\regex_replace_all:nnN {(.*)[\c{_}|.] } { \1 } ##1 /##1 } }
     }
    \seq_use:NV \l_macmadness_output_seq \l__macmadness_list_separator_tl
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \macmadness_print_list:n { V }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_use:Nn { NV }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\listset{./Documents.txt}
\listprint[separator={ \par }]
\end{document}
```

The special line with the regex command is:

```
\seq_put_right:Nn \l_macmadness_output_seq { \__macmadness_action:n { ../\regex_replace_all:nnN {(.*)[\c{_}|.] } { \1 } ##1 /##1 }
```

I think the problem is that the `\regex_replace` does not know to stop after the first `##1` and continues gobbling up tokens. If that is the problem, how could I make it stop reading at that point.

(just FYI, the regular expression is messed up and does not result in what I want anyway.)

I would like the output of that to be:

```
../test1/test1_de.tex
../test1/test1_en.tex
../test2/test2_de.tex
../test2/test2_en.tex
```

Comment: why `separator={ \par }` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It can be anything. It is just used between items in the output. `\par` would list each item vertically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear why you're looking for `\_` when the input file is not expected to have such token.

```
\tl_new:N \l_macmadness_filename_tl 

\cs_new_protected:Npn \macmadness_print_list:n #1
 {
  \seq_if_empty:cTF { l_macmadness_list_#1_seq }
   {
    $\langle$ \textit{empty~list} $\rangle$
   }
   {
    \seq_clear:N \l_macmadness_output_seq
    \seq_map_inline:cn { l_macmadness_list_#1_seq }
     {
      \tl_set:Nn \l_macmadness_filename_tl { ##1 }
      \regex_replace_all:nnN {([^_.]*).*} { \1 } \l_macmadness_filename_tl
      \seq_put_right:Nx \l_macmadness_output_seq
       {
        \exp_not:N \__macmadness_action:n { ../ \l_macmadness_filename_tl / \tl_to_str:n { ##1 } }
       }
      }
    \seq_use:NV \l_macmadness_output_seq \l__macmadness_list_separator_tl
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \macmadness_print_list:n { V }
```

The replacement has already been done by `\regex_replace:nnN` before; I changed the search regex to match all characters until the first underscore or period.

[image]

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\listset}{O{default}m}
 {
  \macmadness_listset:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\listprint}{+O{}}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { macmadness/lists } { #1 }
  \macmadness_print_list:V \l__macmadness_list_name_tl
  \group_end:
 }

\seq_new:N \l__macmadness_list_separator_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \macmadness_listset:nn % Command called by \listset (see above)
 {
  \seq_clear_new:c { l_macmadness_list_#1_seq }
  \tl_set_from_file:Nnn \l_macmadness_file_contents_tl {} {#2}
  \seq_set_split:cnV { l_macmadness_list_#1_seq } { ~ } \l_macmadness_file_contents_tl
  \seq_pop_right:cN { l_macmadness_list_#1_seq } \l_tmpa_tl
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn {cnV}

\keys_define:nn { macmadness/lists }
 {
  name .tl_set:N       = \l__macmadness_list_name_tl,
  name .initial:n      = default,
  action .code:n       = \cs_set_eq:NN \__macmadness_action:n #1,
  action .initial:n    = \use:n,
  separator .tl_set:N  = \l__macmadness_list_separator_tl, % output delimiter
  separator .initial:n = { ,~ }, % output delimiter
 }

\tl_new:N \l_macmadness_filename_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \macmadness_print_list:n #1
 {
  \seq_if_empty:cTF { l_macmadness_list_#1_seq }
   {
    $\langle$ \textit{empty~list} $\rangle$
   }
   {
    \seq_clear:N \l_macmadness_output_seq
    \seq_map_inline:cn { l_macmadness_list_#1_seq }
     {
      \tl_set:Nn \l_macmadness_filename_tl { ##1 }
      \regex_replace_all:nnN {([^_.]*).*} { \1 } \l_macmadness_filename_tl
      \seq_put_right:Nx \l_macmadness_output_seq
       {
        \exp_not:N \__macmadness_action:n { ../ \l_macmadness_filename_tl / \tl_to_str:n { ##1 } }
       }
      }
    \seq_use:NV \l_macmadness_output_seq \l__macmadness_list_separator_tl
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \macmadness_print_list:n { V }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_use:Nn { NV }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\listset{./Documents.txt}
\listprint[separator={ \par }]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've copied your code into mine and it does not work correctly. Are you sure that you did not change anything else? Would you be willing to explain the extra `{ }` where `\exp_not:` is located, and `\exp_not:` itself? That seems to be an important step I was missing. Also, the reason why I was looking for `\_` is because originally, the code was used outside of a LaTeX3 environment. I had to escape the underscore there. Thanks for that correction.

Comment: I see no extra `{ }` next to `\exp_not:N`

Comment: Wherein `\exp_not:N` is located I should have written. There are extra brackets around `\exp_not:N` that are not in my example. The pair just above `{ \seq_use:NV \l_macmadness_output_seq \l__macmadness_list_separator_tl }`

Comment: @macmadness86 Those are for delimiting the argument to `\seq_put_right:Nx`; and `\seq_use:NV...` is not inside braces.

Comment: If I run the example through xelatex or lualatex, I keep getting `..//` and not `../` as in the image. Using TL15 updated today.

Comment: @daleif Fixed (I changed a name in *almost* all places)

Comment: I'm wondering why xelatex or lualatex are needed? Without it the printed `_` disappears

Comment: @daleif It doesn't disappear, as it produces a small dot; with `pdflatex` you have to use T1 encoding.

Comment: @egreg Can I execute an `ExecuteMetaData` command from the `catchfilebetweentags` package on each of the list items that the `listprint` command prints? e.g. like writing some command underneath `\macmadness_print_list:V \l__macmadness_list_name_tl`? Or do I need to loop over the items again? Nevermind, I think I should just redefine the `\macmadness_print_list` protected command. How would you inject `\ExecuteMetaData[filename (item in list)]{mymetatag}`?

Comment: @macmadness86 I don't know; I'd avoid that package and I'm not interested in using or promoting it. Sorry.

Comment: @egreg Why do you set the last list item to a temp variable and remove it from the list without using it? `\seq_pop_right:cN { l_macmadness_list_#1_seq } \l_tmpa_tl` Does this have something to do with reading a file? Is the last item useless?

Comment: @macmadness86 Yes, the last item must be discarded.

Comment: @egreg Why are you so fast to answer these things? I think you have a chip inplant or 6th sense that alerts you upon new stackexchange posts. Thanks :) Another thing: does `\cs_set_eq:NN \__macmadness_action:n #1` just convert the inputted csname/"action" into a `LaTeX3` csname/action? `\__macmadness_action:n` is then called by `\use:n`?

Comment: @macmadness86 `\cs_set_eq:NN \__macmadness_action:n #1` sets `\__macmadnewss_action:n` to be the same as `#1`, which should be a one argument macro (not a “csname”). In this way we can define dynamically the action to use.